# Scale an image if the browser height or width changes but stay in proportion

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my first responsive website, i'm trying to design a landing page so that  the text and images resize depending on the browser size.

I have done this with text but can't figure out how to do it with an image.

Here's a fiddle with my site so far: http://jsfiddle.net/581eg1cx/1/

You'll notice the text gets smaller depending on the height and width, I need to do the same with the image.

i.e if the browser height goes smaller the image will scale down while not overlapping or going under the text and staying centre, same goes for width.

Here's the css for the image part, the rest can be found in the fiddle.

```
.big-logo {
   max-width:auto;
   height:auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 20%;
   left:50%;
   font-size:18px;
   background:blue;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.big-logo img {
   width:100% !important;
   height:100% !important;
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: a responsive website is not just about keeping proportions for every block. You must also consider rearranging the disposition of you elements in the page when the screen gets smaller

Comment: That would be my next step, doesn't really help with this question though?

Comment: No because that was a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/581eg1cx/3/), I think this is what you meant.

the image and container css should be:

```
.big-logo {
   height:50%;
   position: relative;
   font-size:18px;
   background:blue;
   text-align:center;
}

.big-logo img {
   max-width:100%;
   max-height:100%;
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
}
```

I also modified the main-text css as well, have a look.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve can be accomplished through pure CSS. I've altered your fiddle to show you how. Try to get out of the habit of positioning everything absolutely, that way you won't have to set 'top' on every element, let the natural flow of the website do the work.

Also avoid using transform as it's not supported in all browsers, what you are trying to do with translateY can be easily done with negative margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/581eg1cx/4/

```
code
```

Lastly, not everything on a responsive website has to scale, text especially. Work with CSS media queries and set content based on recognised device break points, i.e. 320px wide = iphone. As @single31 states it's also a good idea to change disposition based on these break points.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Chris, media quires scare me a little! I never know what break points I should be designing for, any tips?

Comment: Media queries seem scary but are extremely useful and actually would save you many headaches rather than trying to do font scaling etc, also, as a bonus, no need for JS improving performance and load times.

Lots of resources on the web but as a basic guide try and stick to three or four breakpoints. Small, medium, large maybe extra-large. Peoples screen resolutions differ a lot, so you won't get it 100% perfect but covering 99% of cases is good enough.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that helps but want screen sizes for the small, medium, large and extra large would you use?

Comment: ...continued, iphone (mobile/small) = 320 x 480px, ipad (tablet/medium) = 768 x 1024px, computer screens (large) 1280 x 800px and extra large (HD+) 1920 x 1080px

Best thing to do is download Firefox, press ctrl+shift+m and you can change the resolution mode in which you are viewing the site, shows you what it looks like at preset sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two method one is base on css media tag and another is jquery dynamic function

```
$(window).load(function() {    

    var theWindow        = $(window),
        $img              = $("#img"),
        aspectRatio      = $img.width() / $img.height();

    function resizeBg() {

        if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
            $img
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $img
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgwidth');
        }

    }

    theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

Comment: I see what you've done by adding the classes but care to update the fiddle as I'm still a little stuck. Thanks